# Representation determined by traces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

A discrete, faithful representation of a surface group $G:\pi_1(S_g) \to PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is determined, up to conjugacy by $PGL_2(\mathbb R)$, among such representations by the squares of *traces* of the images of all the elements. I know this follows from the "9g-9" theorem for Teichmuller space: there is a set of $9g-9$ curves whose lengths determine the hyperbolic surface.  The proof I've seen of this is somewhat non-trivial, and involves careful analysis of how lengths change under twists.

My impression is that the first, weaker statement above is also a specific instance of some more general fact about representations into Lie groups -- what is the right statement, and how is it proved?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, it is not even true for $PSL(2,R)$-representations: It is determined up to the action of the full group of automorphism of $PSL(2,R)$ (not all are inner).

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  Is there a specific counter-example you're thinking of?  Maybe one should look at representations with Zariski dense image or something like that to avoid this.

Comment: First of all, keep in mind that for iso.etries of the hyperbolic plane only trace square is well defined. As for examples, conjugate your representation by an orientation reversing isometry.

Comment: That's a good point, I've just edited my question to correct this.  Are there other phenomena that I should be thinking of?